# What is Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so?

Tags: android, crash-reports

I am getting crash while scrolling down and up a listview from my app but the error is not quite understandable. I am attaching the bug report screenshot from Google Developer Console.

Please go through it.

**Adapter getView Code:**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_item_list,
                parent, false);
        holder.labelName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.item_label);
        holder.labelInfo = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.item_info);
        holder.mImgArrow = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow);
        holder.mImgIcon = (RoundCornerImage) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        holder.relative_cell_view = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.relative_cell_view);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    appSharedPrefrence = AppSharedPrefrence.getsharedprefInstance(context);

    final FileBean dataBean = dataList.get(position);
    holder.labelName.setText(position+" : "+dataBean.getName());
    holder.labelInfo.setText(replace_comma(dataBean.getinfo()));

    try{
        ImageLoader.getImageLoader(context).DisplayImage(dataBean.getImageUrl(), holder.mImgIcon,R.drawable.logo);
    }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){

    }       
return convertView; }
```

[image]

This is the above crash report i am getting , please let me know and suggest me some solution.

Comment: Put your adapter's getView code.

Comment: i update the post , please check

Comment: I think its ART runtime issue, take a look at [this](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable/issues/70).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code fails in a native function named `jpeg_start_decompress()` in the library `libjpeg.so`, so my best guess is that you are trying to display a corrupted JPEG file or something like that.

If you have access to the images, I would suggest you to try to open them all on your computer and see if there isn't one that fails to load.

Comment: Yes , i agree with you , some of the images may be corrupt which are stored in my server... i need to look into it...