# Application crash without logcat entry

Tags: java, android, crash, android-logcat

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364373/android-app-crashes-without-any-logcat-or-any-exception) that application crashes without logcat entries due to some [Native crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920453/what-is-native-crash-at-system-lib-libc-so). As in Android Studio 2.3.3 the logcat has both **Verbose** and **No filters** options are set by default:[image: Logcat] Well what are the ways of solving native crashes or identify these crashes?
My application is crashing on opening `MapsActivity` more than two times i.e on third(**edit :** now fourth) click to open brings it to crash.
Here is my `MapsActivity` it receives `Location List` from the `MainActivity` and adds markers to the Map on those locations.

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
ArrayList<Location> locs = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String jsonString = bundle.getString("KEY_LOCATIONS");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listOfLocationType = new TypeToken<List<Location>>() {
    }.getType();
    locs = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listOfLocationType);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    setUpMap();
}

public void setUpMap() {

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       return;}
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

    addMarkeratLocation();
}

public void addMarkeratLocation() {
    int i;
    double lt=0.0,lg=0.0;
    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.dottt);
    LatLng addpoint = new LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
    for (i = 0; i < locs.size(); i++) {
        lt=locs.get(i).getLatitude();
        lg=locs.get(i).getLongitude();
        addpoint = new LatLng(lt,lg );
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(addpoint).icon(icon));

    }
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(addpoint));
    LatLng camloc= new LatLng(lt,lg);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(camloc, 15));

}
}
```

And this is from where in `MainActivity` the `MapsActivity` is being fired.

```
direction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Showing directions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(MainActivity.this);
            olati=tinydb.getDouble("destination_lati",lati);
            olongi=tinydb.getDouble("destination_longi",longi);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonString = gson.toJson(locs);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("KEY_LOCATIONS",jsonString);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I don't know what of Logcat shall I post. How do I sort it out? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :** Added Error Logcat
This is something around where the application crashes

> 12-06 00:12:06.190 18296-18307/com.example.acer.mylocationmap A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x40 in tid 18307 (FinalizerDaemon)
>   12-06 00:12:07.800 3624-3624/? E/audit: type=1701 msg=audit(1512499327.795:2175): auid=4294967295 uid=10495 gid=10495 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 pid=18307 comm="FinalizerDaemon" reason="memory violation" sig=11
>   12-06 00:12:07.845 2845-20348/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
>   12-06 00:12:07.845 2845-20348/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
>   12-06 00:12:07.930 2845-2925/? E/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   12-06 00:12:07.930 2845-2925/? E/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   12-06 00:12:07.990 20349-20349/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
>   12-06 00:12:07.990 20349-20349/? E/Zygote: v2
>   12-06 00:12:07.995 20349-20349/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
>   12-06 00:12:07.995 20349-20349/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
>   12-06 00:12:15.020 2845-2889/? E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: select your app and your device in filter then rerun it.

Comment: Have you tried changing from "Verbose" to "Error"?.

Comment: @Ninja Got this as the last line in logcat for first crash `A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xd457b008 in tid 8634 (GLThread 31225)`

Comment: @BluRe.CN tried but not able to understand anything in it... Shall I post the "Error" logcat?

Comment: yes, share your error log. Other think is it might happen if something wrong with your GL. I don't think so that is happen with google map. where you test your project(Emulator or Device)?

Comment: @Ninja I'm testing the project on device

Answer (score 0):

Check your build variant has debug set to true in the build.gradle file

This is commonly set to false on release versions of applications as it is a requirement for publishing to the play store .

Comment: build.gradle file of Application or Module? Is this what you saying? `buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }`

Comment: Your Module build.gradle file. I also see you are using android studio. Android studio has a built in debugger, so you can put break points (click next to line number in file and a red blob should appear) by suspicious code, and step through as necessary, this should help pin point exactly where it is breaking. [debugging in  android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html)